# Is Delta Live Table available with Scala?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, delta-live-tables

Documentation about Delta live tables says nothing about Scala support, only Python and SQL  are mentioned https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta-live-tables/. In Databricks guide no scala too https://www.databricks.com/discover/pages/getting-started-with-delta-live-tables. It is looks strange for me as scala one of the pupolar languages in big data processing. Is it possible to use DLT with Scala?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Scala is not supported by Delta Live Tables (DLT) at this time.

https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/dlt-support-for-scala/td-p/35943